# Rig a body with mirror modifier

Tags: rigging, mirror

I'm trying to create and rig a simple human-ish body, I successfully created the body and the skeleton and parented it and it works, except that the bones on one hand control both. How would one go about making the rigging work where half the body is mirrored?
Thanks

[image: Screenshot of body]

Answer (score 1):

Put the *Mirror* modifier above the *Armature* and it should work fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already have the mirror above the mirror modifier - https://imgur.com/a/6PO22fk. It seems weird

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/0030ff85f22442428713de55b25d4bb5 this is the file

Comment: yes it seems to fail for no reason, even though the Vertex Groups option is enabled in the Mirror modifier, I would personally apply the Mirror modifier, because anyway you'll probably have to bring some corrections